# Scrolling Performance in WebView for Android - Jelly Bean 4.1.x

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

I'm working on a PhoneGap project and I've noticed that in Jelly Bean (4.1.x), scrolling is laggy and slow. I've tried to add transform3d to the scrollable elements but that didn't help. I can't add hardwareAccerlerated to the manifest because we need to support 2.3.x.

Any suggestions on how to make the WebView scroll better on Android? I've stripped out all the CSS to make it basic.

This occurs on 2.0.0 of PhoneGap.

You can see a video of this here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j17do2gry8vxhzo/scrollvdeo.mov

Comment: @mtmurdock Having done several Android web projects for clients, I have to *strongly* disagree.

Comment: On what point? That PhoneGap is the problem, or that Android 4.1+ is "buttery"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured you the issue. You need to set the target for your application to 3.0, and then set the minSDK attribute in our manifest file to be your lowest support OS. Then add android:hardwareAccelerated=true to the manifest. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @gregavola You need to correct your spelling. Should be: <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

Comment: @LarryAasen this should be fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

What caused this BUG for me was that I was using the phonegap android example (/phonegap/lib/android/example) which has the hardwareAccerlerated=true in the WRONG place in the AndroidManifest.xml.

It SHOULD be in the application element instead of the manifest element

Now this works like a charm.

I'm using Phonegap 2.1

Answer (score 1):

The android developer site below references this as well.  Made use of the attribute and it works brilliantly!

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html